# How to force UI Display to update in swift?

Tags: swift, user-interface, updates

I'm trying to get the View Controller to update while I'm in a loop that calls a function that does tons of Label updates. But the update to the screen doesn't happen until I've finished the loop.

Is there a way to force a UI update before continuing? Something like forcing data to be written to a disk.

code for the button to start the loop is something like this:

```
        while (match.currentInnings == currentInnings)
        {
            playSingleBall()
            if (gameover == true)
            {
                return
            }
        }
```

After playSingleBall, I'd like to force a UI update before continuing.

Thanks.

Comment: Presuming that this is running on the main thread, the UI update can't happen until after you exit your loop. If you want to update the UI, you have to do the above loop on a background thread and then dispatch UI updates to the main thread like Salman said. Or better, retire this `while` loop entirely.

Comment: @Lankybrit What element of your UI are you trying to update here? Also loops often cause issues with memory usage so I'd stay away from them.

Comment: Inside playSingleBall, it calculates the results and then updates the whole display. That's about 40 Labels in all.

Answer (score 4):

**Call it in Dispatch Queue:**

**Swift 3.x**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    updateYourUI()
}
```

**Swift 2.x**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
   updateYourUI()       
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What does UpdateUI refer to? There's no UpdateUI in ViewController.

Comment: It just means to add your logic or make your function and call it in Dispatch Main Block for UI update. Update UI is anything you want, code or a function.

Comment: The function have your code means in call the function here where you want to update the UI..

Comment: FYI - With Swift 4 out now, there's really no point in posting Swift 2 code in answers.

Comment: That is a better way to answer because one answer can help other people there are many people who code with Swift 2.x.

Comment: @rmaddy With another word there is no special tag like swift3 or 4 or 2.

Comment: I can't get DispatchQueue.main.async to work at all. When I put playSingleBall inside it, it just hangs when it gets there. Is that because I'm within a button action, and not in the main View Controller code?